# not able to invoke PSP apps using UPI URI

Tags: android, android-intent, payment, upi

To start with -

I am aware that there is a similar question out there which is answered. However the answer is not helping me.

[Invoke PSP app with UPI url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384561/invoke-psp-app-with-upi-url)

My Problem is same -

Using UPI url as below

```
    String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=xsas@hdfcbank&pn=ABC+DEF&mc=qy67vt&tr=12121&tn=your+order+with+us&am=1.5&url=shopify.com";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(UPI));
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
```

The moment I use setData, I stop getting list of Apps with which I can share this (the list is empty). If I remove setData, the regular list of Apps (sms, email etc) start popping and bank app (which accepts UPI, say ICICI/HDFC) is not one of them.

What could be going wrong here?,

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=xsas@hdfcbank&pn=ABC+DEF&mc=qy67vt&tr=12121&tn=your+order+with+us&am=1.5&url=shopify.com";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(UPI));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
```

with this:

```
String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=xsas@hdfcbank&pn=ABC+DEF&mc=qy67vt&tr=12121&tn=your+order+with+us&am=1.5&url=shopify.com";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); // this line needs to be updated
intent.setData(Uri.parse(UPI));
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
```

This is because for all the deeplinked upi apps to handle the incoming intent, they need to be called with View Action.

Comment: This update also does not work. 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
also I am getting undefined response while using "pockets" app of icici

Answer (score 0):

you can omit the `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);` part from your intent as that's not mandatory and different apps will handle different actions.

as you can see in the original question you referred there is no `setAction`